# Collapse a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 divs side by side divA and divB. I have a maximize button on top of divB.
When I click on button on divB, the divB should occupy the space of divA and become bigger, divA should be collapsed.
While clicking once again , it should be restored to normal size.
How to get this functionality using jquery?

Comment: you need to share your code(html, css & script)... and what you have already tried

Comment: This is not a best way to ask a question here .. Add some code you used.. and if not started with code start for it.. heres a fiddle link for reference http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/eK8X5/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to use jQuery's toggle() or animate() function. Viraj Nalawade gave you a good example of how to use slideToggle and collapse one div.

I give you here another example that include two divs, side by side: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q0h2qsoL/2/) or see snippet below:

```js
var original_width=$("#divA").width();
var max_width=original_width*18/10;
var min_width=original_width*2/10;
var div_status = {};
$("button").click(function () {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    var sibling = $(parent).siblings();
    var parent_id = $(parent).attr("id");
    var sibling_id = $(sibling).attr("id");

    if (div_status[parent_id]) {
        div_status[parent_id] = false;
    } else {
        div_status[parent_id] = true;
        div_status[sibling_id] = false;
    }
   
    if (div_status[parent_id]) {
        $(parent).animate({
            width: max_width+"px"
        });
        $(sibling).animate({
            width: min_width+"px"
        });
    } else {
        $(parent).animate({
            width: original_width+"px"
        });
        $(sibling).animate({
            width: original_width+"px"
        });
    }
});
```

```css
#container {
    width:500px;  
    float:left;
}
div.mobile {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    height:200px;    
}
#divA {
    background-color:red;
}
#divB {
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div id="divA" class="mobile">
        <button>divA</button>
    </div>
    <div id="divB" class="mobile">
        <button>divB</button>
    </div>
</div>
```